# Error "New connection from #IP_address on port 1833. Client <unknown> closed its connection" on Ubuntu server by Mosquitto MQTT Broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

My device which is GSM based device placed at remote location is sending message to server on TCP protocol to publish MQtt message. But getting error as shown in figure on server where mosquitto service is running.

Error Details :
1236974 New Connection from #IP_address on port 1833.
1236974 Client  closed its connection.

[image]

at the same time i can able to connect mosquitto broker(server) from MQTTBox or other application available on windows/android.

from LTE/Gsm based device I am communicating with the below code:

```
type hvoid connsetup()
{ wdt_reset();
  Serial.println("AT+CMQTTSTART");
  delay(1000); wdt_reset();
  Serial.print("AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,");
  Serial.print('"');
  Serial.print(MQTTClientID);
  Serial.println('"');
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("AT+CMQTTCONNECT=0,\"tcp://52.XX.XX.XXX:1883\",14,1,\"userid12\",\"password123\"");
  delay(3000);  wdt_reset();
  serialEvent();
}
```

Please help me out what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots/images of text, post the actual text and use the toolbar to fomat it (as code). Screenshots are hard to read, impossible for people that use screen readers and not searchable.

Comment: You also need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76931063/edit) the question to include a lot more information about where that code runs and what device it's driving (some MQTT enabled LTE device?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.